# How to make discord fetch faster for usernames for multiple users with discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, discord.js

Here's my code:

```
const memberGroup = ["801555002664419350", "801555002664419351", "801555002664419352", "801555002664419353", "801555002664419354", "801555002664419355", "801555002664419356", "801555002664419357", "801555002664419358", "801555002664419359", "801555002664419360", "801555002664419361", "801555002664419362", "801555002664419363", "801555002664419364"];
let namesArr = [];
for (i=0; i < queryLength2; i++) {
      namesArr .push(await message.guild.members.fetch({ user: memberGroup[i] }).catch((err) => { }));
 }
console.log(namesArr);
```

I'm using a for loop to fetch the members from the array with the api. However, this takes **7-9 seconds** to return the result for the 15 ids in the memberGroup array. Doing it with 30 ids doubles the load time for **up to 16 seconds**. Probably the reason why it takes too long is that 90% of the users on the memberGroup array are not members of the server anymore (left the server), hence they return undefined.

Is there a way to make this faster? **My plan is to list 30 users** on the list/leaderboard and display their usernames using the.user.username. The list should still display the users who are not part of the server anymore. And then replace undefined values that the fetch returns for non-members with just the IDs later.

Note: I don't like to use tags here with the <@ID>.

List/leaderboard should look something like this:

> Leaderboard:
>
> 1. 801555002664419350
> 2. Ben
> 3. Mark
> 4. 801555002664419353
> 5. 801555002664419354

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, your loop is waiting for each promise to resolve, before going to the next username. You could speed up your code using `await Promise.all(...)`.

The [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) function takes an array of promises and run all of them at the same time. It will wait for all of them to be done before going forward with the code.

To do so, you can push each promises into an array, without calling `await` on them.

Then, you can `await` the `Promise.all` function, by passing it they array you just build.

The output of that function will also be an array, containing each promises response in the order that they had in the promise array.

```js
const memberGroup = [/* ... */];
let namesArrPromises = [];

for (i=0; i < queryLength2; i++) {
      namesArrPromises.push(message.guild.members.fetch({ user: memberGroup[i] }).catch((err) => { }));
 }

const namesArr = await Promise.all(namesArrPromises);

console.log(namesArr);
```

As a side note, you should avoid mixing  `then().catch()` with `await`. If you want to catch the error, you should use a `try {} catch {}`

```js
const memberGroup = [/* ... */];
let namesArrPromises = [];

for (i=0; i < queryLength2; i++) {
      namesArrPromises.push(message.guild.members.fetch({ user: memberGroup[i] }));
 }

try {
    const namesArr = await Promise.all(namesArrPromises);
} catch (err) {
    /* do something with the error */
}

console.log(namesArr);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the try/catch be around the `await Promise.all`? I don't think the fetch will throw because it runs inside a Promise.

Comment: You're right, my bad. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Nicolas, it's throwing an error of "unknown member". The array contains discord ids of users that are not part of the server. For cases like this, how do I approach this with Promise.all? The list should still display the users who are not part of the server anymore like the example I provided on the last part of my question.

Comment: You could wrap the `message.guild.members.fetch({ user: memberGroup[i] })` part in an async function, with a try catch, and do nothing in the catch clause.